# calling a c#.net function from javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am creating an application using C#.net.
I am trying to update my page as soon as data in the database is updated.
I have stored one value from the database in one label and i am calling a function each time which is storing the same value in another label and after that i am comaparing the two labels.
The code is

my webpage.aspx.cs is

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString;
        if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT name from Master where id= 10"), con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(ds);
        Label2.Text = Convert.ToString(ds1);
    }
    protected String CodeBehind()
    {
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT name from Master where id= 10"), con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(ds);
        String ds2 = Convert.ToString(ds1);
        return (ds2);
    }
    protected int compare()
    {
        string abc = Label2.Text;
        string abcd = Label3.Text;
        if (abc == abcd)
        { 
            return(0);
        }
        else
        {
            return (1);
        }
     }
 }
```

and my front end javascript code is

```
 <script type="text/JavaScript">
    function AutoRefresh() {
        document.getElementById('<%= Label3.ClientID %>').innerHTML = '<%= CodeBehind() %>';
        var res = '<%= compare() %>'
        if ( res == 1) {
            alert("same");
            setTimeout("location.reload(true);", 60000);
        }
        else {
         alert("different")
             abx();
         }
     }
     function abx() {
         AutoRefresh();
     }
```

But there is a problem as when i am calling the function codebehind, it is executing the whole backend code thus the value of both the labels is updated at the same time.

I just want to call the code behind function every time and want to update the value of label2 just once.
 can some tell me how can i do it.

Comment: a infinite (never ending) loop is created in AutoRefresh() when you call abx();

Comment: Looks like you need AJAX

Comment: @sajanyamaha i want the page to regularly check for any update in the database that's why i have used this loop

Comment: If you are refreshing the entire page, why do you need to store the previous value and the updated value and then do a comparison? Why can't you just refresh the page without that logic, which will give you the updated value.

Comment: @wired_in i want the page to update only when this value is updated in the database

Comment: Nevermind, you are extremely confused on how the browser (client) interacts with the server. See Spikeh's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call a C# function from JavaScript - if that was possible, imagine what those with malicious intent could do?

You need to use Ajax here, and POST / GET the information from your web forms.

Your JavaScript code does nothing but reload your page - which means a full page load cycle will take place, hence why all of your code is executing. You're also mixing up client and server side code, and misunderstanding how the ASPX engine renders its content.

I use [JQuery for my Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (you can do it without, but JQuery makes it a lot quicker and easier), but you also need to make your function accessible by the Ajax call. Use a callback to update your label:

```
  $.ajax({
          url: "/url/to/your/post/page"
         }).done(function ( data ) {
                    // Check validity of "data"
                      $("#label2").val("Updated!"); 
        });
```

It's worth noting that you can do a hell of a lot more. See my link for the $ajax() documentation.

In terms of "/url/to/your/post/page", because you are using web forms, you will need to create a page that returns the correct content to your ajax function. I'll post some more info later on.

You really need to get your head around what the difference is between JavaScript and C# first, before you try and do something as complex as timed AJAX callbacks - your <%=%> tags are rendered before the HTML is output to the client, and the client has absolutely no visibility of your C# class or its methods.

Comment: It's worth noting that without some more complex push/pull implementation, your page won't be updated as soon as something changes in the database. You'll have to make the ajax call in intervals to check and see if there is an updated value, so in essence you're going to have a bunch of unnecessary ajax requests, especially if the database isn't updated often.

Comment: Yes, and if you need to let the server control your clients, then SignalIR is the way to go, as the JS / C# implementation would get very complex, very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to identify your approach. This can be done int two ways.

1. Keep polling your server for every `x` seconds to see if the value is changes or not. For this you can use AJAX call to either a [AJAX Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163499.aspx) or a [PageMethods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/). In both the cases you cannot access the controls in the page. If you want to access the controls your whole page event life cycle will trigger (which is your current problem).
2. Make your server signal your client that the value is changed. This can be done through various techniques. The best way is to use a [SignalR](http://signalr.net) library.

Using SignalR will help you scale your application easily.

Answer (score 0):

Update your code accordingly:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString;
        if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
        con.Open();
        }

        Label2.Text = CodeBehind();
    }
}

protected String CodeBehind()
{
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT name from Master where id= 10"), con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adp.Fill(ds);
    String ds2 = Convert.ToString(ds1);        
    return (ds2);
}
```

And remove this line from function AutoRefresh()

```
setTimeout("location.reload(true);", 60000);
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: sorry but it is still executing the whole code again on calling CodeBehind().

Comment: @user1852933 : what is the result coming in  var res = '<%= compare() %>' ??

Comment: i think the location.reload(true) is causing the full postback, thats why the whole code in Page_Load is executing again.

Comment: setTimeout("location.reload(true);", 60000); line is added in order to check the database every 60 sec for any update. removing it will not solve the issue

Comment: But the codebehind() also checks the database for changes, u dont need to reload the page, that will reset all the controls and their values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement this by using ASP.NET AJAX, you can use UpdatePanel and Timer Controls, here is a tutorial [Tutorial: How to refresh an UpdatePanel control at a timed interval](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295400.aspx) otherwise you can use jQuery Ajax.

Answer (score -1):

try to use Page.IsPostBack property